# Capsule Collider stuck on floor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the basic RigidbodyController. I created some rooms with cubes as walls and planes as floors and celeing.

But the player, that uses the Rigidbody Controller (the controller needs a Capsule Collider in order to work), often stucks and freezes, "crashing" on the floor. Checking the scene in the editor, the collider is exactly tangential to the floor, so It should work, but it doesn't.

Any soluition?

Comment: Did you try to have it a bit above the ground initially? So that it drops slightly when you start.

Comment: @GunnarB.If you mean increasing the y value of GameObject's position, I already did that.

Comment: Which collision detection mode are you using on the rigidbody? Maybe try to change to another one. Also, is that one of the assets you can use? The first or third person controllers work pretty well.

Comment: @JoeBlow Did it, but same issues. 
GunnarB. I tried discrete, continuous and dynamic continuous with no differences

Comment: Maybe this can help you, there are a couple common mistakes listed http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-fix-common-physics-problems-in-your-game--cms-21418

Comment: @GunnarB. Great! It worked! The problem was that the player had both PlayerController and CapsuleCollider attached.